# How to code data in a sql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm guessing there are lots of ways to do this, so I'm stuck on determining the best way.

But, I have different methods that I use to determine a path.

```
a) relative to folder
b) relative to root
c) absolute
d) default
etc., etc.
```

I need this information saved to a sql table.

I was going to just use a varchar of length 1 with no default, and put the letter associated with each method in the table.  Then, I was going to put a "key" in the PHP code so others would know what each letter stands for.

Is this a good way to do it.  Should I use a more descriptive coding and eliminate writing out a key?

What is best practice?

Comment: are you talking about url? Or you need to add "type" in DB row to know how to use the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put keys in `enum` column type with set e.g. "folder","root","absolute","default"

Comment: no length - in length/value field you define only set of values - in your case all possible values: "folder","root","absolute","default"